# Trac - Git integration

Tags: git, version-control, trac

Is it possible to setup trac with git to do the following.

1.) Given a ticket, identify which files were changed.

2.) (The inverse) - given a file, identify for which tickets it was modified.

Is there a way to setup this functionality with trac and git integration by - Where upon commit the ticket number is specified in the commit message causing the file names to be associated with the trac ticket in question.

Answer (score 1):

Related functionality is provided by the [CommitTicketUpdater](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater) component of Trac.

It (1) addes comments to all mentioned tickets with direct links from ticket (comment) to changeset. (2) File to ticket associations are visible via file's commit history: Links from changeset commit messages to ticket(s) are generated too, if you write #123 (TracLinks shortcut syntax) or ticket:123 instead of ticket 123, because messages support [WikiFormatting](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiFormatting#TracLinks).

Comment: The Ticket Changesets Plugin (http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracTicketChangesetsPlugin) is useful when used with this Trac component.  It adds a box to each ticket listing all the revisions associated with it in one central location.